# Vue unicons - set viewBox in custom icon

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have just installed the [Vue Unicons](https://github.com/antonreshetov/vue-unicons) module in my vue project.

Vue version: 2.6.10
Vue unicons version: 3.3.1

I am trying to create my own custom icons [as explained here](https://github.com/antonreshetov/vue-unicons#add-custom-icons):

**custom-icons.js:**

```
export const myTestIcon = {
    name: 'myTestIcon',
    style: 'line',
    viewBox: '0 0 680 680',
    path: '<path d="M 635 497 l 1 -466 l -620 0 L 20 640 L 516 643 L 231 221z"></path>';
}
```

**app.js:**

```
import Unicon from 'vue-unicons/dist/vue-unicons-vue2.umd';
import { myTestIcon } from './custom-icons';
Unicon.add([myTestIcon]);
```

**App.vue:**

```
<unicon name="my-test-icon"></unicon>
```

Although I set `viewBox` is the icon definition, the icon is rendered with default value of viewBox (`0 0 24 24`).

If I add `viewBox="0 0 650 650"` or even `v-bind="{viewBox:'0 0 650 650'}"` to the `<unicon>` element, it works fine. But I cannot do it since I use icons dynamically.

I read [in this place](https://githubmemory.com/repo/antonreshetov/vue-unicons/issues/27) that it might happen due to compilation, but the answer did not help me.

Any idea how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom icon definition schema does not include a `viewBox` property, so setting it in your definition has no effect. Specifically, Vue Unicons only [reads `name`, `style`, and `path`](https://github.com/antonreshetov/vue-unicons/blob/1cd71d891b90682c68390a75a31919e0b4a5de74/src/components/Unicon.vue#L73) from the custom icon definition.

The `viewBox` can only be set as a [prop on the `<unicon>` component](https://github.com/antonreshetov/vue-unicons/blob/b8f75dd/src/components/Unicon.vue#L8):

```html
<unicon name="my-custom-icon"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32" 
        width="64"
        height="64" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-viewbox-on-unicon?file=src/App.vue)